# ZSH claims "invalid argument" when redirecting scanimage to a timestamped file on SMB

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, zsh, timestamp

I've been scratching my head on this one for a little too long, so maybe someone here will be able to see what's going wrong. I'm trying to build a command to scan from my scanner to a timestamped file in my documents.

```
scanimage -d "pixma:04A91746_57E9C3" --resolution 300 --format tiff > $(date +%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S).tiff
```

This produces the error `zsh: invalid argument: 2017.05.27-14:29:13.tiff`

Oddly enough, removing the seconds in the date format string like so, the error doesn't occur, but the file is not named properly either:

```
scanimage -d "pixma:04A91746_57E9C3" --resolution 300 --format tiff > $(date +%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M).tiff
```

I end up with a file named `2017.05.27-14`, missing the minutes and the .tiff extension.

To further complicate things, this all works perfectly when not in a samba share, but the same commands in a samba share prompts the error. Testing with echo instead of scanimage don't reveal anything interesting as using echo causes it to behave as expected.

Comment: What happens when you use double quotes? `… > "$(date +%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S).tiff"`

Comment: This works fine for me with bash and zsh: `echo foo > $(date +%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S).tiff`

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Quotes don't appear to change anything.

Comment: @Cyrus It appears to work in echo, but not with scanimage. Furthermore, I've discovered another quirk that seems to really further complicate things: This problem only occurs when I'm scanning to a samba share AND I am redirecting the output of scanimage as opposed to echo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turns out to have been the colons - since my samba share doesn't allow filenames with colons, it would give this error. Removing the colons from my filename results in it working perfectly:

```
scanimage -d "pixma:04A91746_57E9C3" --resolution 300 --format tiff > $(date +%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S).tiff
```

If anyone is curious about the completed script for scanning and organizing documents, here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash
finish="-1"
page=1
date=$(date +%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S)
while [ "$finish" = '-1' ]; do
  echo -e "\e[1m\e[32m==>\e[0m Scanning page $page..."
  scanimage -d "pixma:04A91746_57E9C3" --resolution 300 --format tiff > $date-$page.tiff
  while true; do
    echo -en "  \e[1m\e[34m->\e[0m More pages? [y/n] "
    read answer
    case $answer in
      [Yy]* ) page=$((page+1)); break;;
      [Nn]* ) finish="1"; break;;
      * ) echo -e "  \e[1m\e[34m->\e[0m Please answer tes or no.";;
    esac
  done
done
echo -e "\e[1m\e[32m==>\e[0m Converting $page page(s) to PDF..."
convert $date-*.tiff $date.pdf
echo -e "\e[1m\e[32m==>\e[0m Cleaning up..."
rm $date-*.tiff
```

I just cd into whatever folder (receipts, medical, etc) and run scanfile. Result is a timestamped pdf of all pages scanned in the current directory.